# Using two successHandlers in one application SpringSecurity

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I need redirecting to different pages after logging depending on Role of user. I use class CustomSuccess Handler for this purpose:

```
@Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String url = determineTargetUrl(authentication);
        if(response.isCommitted()){
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, url);

    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication){

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = 
                                authentication.getAuthorities();
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        for(GrantedAuthority authority: authorities){
            roles.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }

        if(roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            return "/admin/adminPage";
        }else if(roles.contains("ROLE_USER")){
            return "/personal/profile";
        }else return "/login";
    }


}
```

And I need SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler for redirecting to targetUrl, if one exists.

```
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler 
                savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

               SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler auth 
                    = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        auth.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");
        return auth;
    }
```

Method http.successHandler(...) overrides previous value of successHandler.
How can I use both this classes in my application? Help please)